# saving session to public_html

Tags: php, apache, session

am developing a site where I have two separate designs(views). the first view  index.php is on the root of my public_html folder while the second is in a sub-folder named mobile (that is public_html/mobile) also on the root of public_html I have a file named sessn.php which I included (using php include "sessn.php";) in both index.php and mobile/index.php, inside sessn.php I specified a path (secf) to save session using
ini_set('session.save_path','secf');

my challenge is that everything works fine when on index.php but if I goto mobile/index.php I get invalid path and I will have to create another folder mobile/secf so session file to be saved in. Any way to save session from both index.php and mobile/index.php to the same folder?

Comment: Use ../ to go up a level.  Damn typing on an iPod is slow :(. First answer goes to Scyld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm… try this in **mobile/index.php**:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '../secf');
```

Cheers,

Comment: ini_set('session.save_path', 'secf'); is in sessn.php which is in the root of public_html, I am using the same file to start session in mobile/index.php by saying include "sessn.php"; where I want to start session. I don't think your answer will work

Comment: Then use absolute path '/home/username/public_html/secf' or move ini_set() to both index.php files.